# Embed images from swf file in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-cs5, flex4.6

How to create vector images swf file in flash, and how can i use the swf file to get images in flex.

Could you please some one help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a swf file created in Flash CS6 (or similar) that you wish to use in a flex project. Is this correct?

If it is, then you would use swfloader to load your swf file in a flex app.

example:

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import mx.managers.CursorManager;
[Bindable]
public var loadModHome:String = "assets/flashFiles/home_trusted.swf"; 

protected function analyticsBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{   
loadModHome="assets/flashFiles/home_trusted.swf";   
}

protected function integratedBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
loadModHome="assets/flashFiles/home_integrated.swf";    
}

]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Then in your component/app/module etc place the swfloader tag and fill it in as needed. Here I have bound the source to a variable called "loadModHome" this makes the swfloader dynamic in that I can assign a new value to my variable and have it unload and load different swf files. I do this by using the click event of two buttons, this allows me to toggle the swf files on the fly

```
<mx:LinkButton id="analyticsBtn"  label="Trusted Analytics" textDecoration="underline"
color="blue" click="analyticsBtn_clickHandler(event)"/>
<mx:LinkButton id="integratedBtn" label="Integrated Billing" textDecoration="underline"
color="blue" click="integratedBtn_clickHandler(event)"/>

<s:SWFLoader id="homeMainSL" x="127" y="10" width="600" height="800" 
source="{loadModHome}" click="homeMainSL_clickHandler(event)" 
useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true"/>
```

To see a working example check out http://www.myfirerules.net. The site is a work in progress. The home page has a s:SWFLoader tag to load the Flash created swf files, the other pages use a s:ModuleLoader tag instead to load swf files created by flex.

Hope this helps

Jim